# Django Foreign Key in View - get first image to show for each user in list

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make my dashboard show a list of users in your area. This so far works but I can not get the user's fist image to show. The current error message I am getting is "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'"

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, default='profile_image/none/no-img.png')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=False)
```

views.py

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 've/cp/dashboard.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashboardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        user = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        try:
            favorite = Favorite.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
            favorites = favorite.users.all()
        except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
            favorites = None

        args = {
            'users': users, 'favorites':favorites, 'images': Images.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

dashboard.html

```
        <h2>People near you</h2>
        {% for user in users %}
            <a href="{% url 've:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                <h4>{{ user.username }}</h4>
                <p>{{ user.images }}</p>

            {% if images %}

                {% for img in images %}
                <a href="{{ img.image.url }}" target="_blank">
                <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="" style="max-width: 300px">
                </a>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}

            <p>No images</p>
            {% endif %}

            </a>

            {% if not user in favorites %}
            <a href="{% url 've:change_favorites' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Favorite</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)` return queryset. When yoy try later `Images.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)` it raise error. You need to get first object in queryset with [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#first) method:

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
```

Or use [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

but second option will raise `DoesNotExist` error if user with provided id does not exist. To handle this error you can use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), which return page not found in case of wrong id:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=1)
```

Comment: I tried it with 'get' and got the error you mentioned. Switched it back to filter and added the .first() and now getting the " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' " error.

Comment: @AlexWinkler yep, first will return none if no objects found. You need to check `if user:` each time. Or use get_object_or_404. See update in answer.

Comment: Nice thanks! That fixed the error but still no images. Think it could be an issue with my dashboard.html code?

Comment: @AlexWinkler hm.. maybe but I dont see errors in template. Did you add media_root to settings and url? Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Mmm yes, I have images working throughout the site and on the profile and edit user pages specifically. I think I'm missing something identifying the class of the images.

Comment: @AlexWinkler sorry, i dont see the reason of this problem.

Comment: Solved with help of similar question and answer from 
@neverwalkaloner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150613/django-foreign-key-class-not-showing/49150707#49150707