# Django Foreign Key class not showing

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

The goal is to have a dashboard show a list of users in your area. The list of users works and it shows the Username. The only issue is I can't get the users images (ideally just have 1st image) to show. There are no error messages currently. Just nothing appearing.

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, default='profile_image/none/no-img.png')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=False)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 've/cp/dashboard.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashboardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)

        try:
            favorite = Favorite.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
            favorites = favorite.users.all()
        except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
            favorites = None

        args = {
            # 'users': users, 'favorites':favorites, 'images': images,
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

dashboard.html

```
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2>People near you</h2>
            {% for user in users %}
                <a href="{% url 've:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">

                    <!--THIS WORKS-->
                    <h4>{{ user.username }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ user.profile.bio }}</p>

                    <!--But not this... why..-->
                    <p>{{ user.images.image.url }}</p>

                ''' 
                Or this.. However it does work on view_profile page where 
                there is a pk. Seem like it's not finding images for users, 
                as this results in a "No images message on localhost 
                '''
                {% if images %}
                    {% for img in images %}
                    <a href="{{ user.img.image.url }}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{{ user.img.image.url }}" class="" style="max-width: 300px">
                    </a>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                <p>No images</p>
                {% endif %}
                </a>

                <!-- Favorites works great -->
                {% if not user in favorites %}
                <a href="{% url 've:change_favorites' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Favorite</button>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user's images direcly from user object using `images_set` attribute.

In your case you can do something like this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% with first_image=user.images_set.first %} 
        {% if first_image %} 
            <a href="{{ first_image.image.url }}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{{ first_image.image.url }}" class="" style="max-width: 300px">
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: omg there is a god. I've tried everything to figure this out and didn't want to keep asking here. Thank you so much! If you have any recommended reading or ways to get better in this specific area please let me know. I've read almost everything remotely related to ForeignKeys in the Django docs to fix this.

Comment: @AlexWinkler Probably you already saw it, but check this part of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects it's about query related objects. `model_set` syntax also described there.